# Rails - Strong Parameters and attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Rails newb, just working on my first app and my first coding experience outside of a little python and bash for sysadmin type work.  Using rails 4.1 on C9 and kind of curious why I am experiencing a situation.  From what I have read regarding using strong parameters, this replaces the old Rails 3 use of attr_accessible.

I am using devise and setup auth on my app, then wanted to add some custom fields like username and zipcode to be updated via a user profile page.  Here is the code that I have to accomplish this.  From what I have read the strong parameters should be moved from the model into the controller.

app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb # this inherits the devise::reg

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :zipcode, :password_confirmation)
end

def account_update_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :zipcode, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end
```

However, even after adding this it is still not saving the fields via my /users/edit page without the addition of the following.

app/models/user.rb

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :zipcode
```

Once the username and zipcode symbols (not sure of that is the correct term) have been added to the user.rb then the database is populated.  The only thing I can think of is the fact that I added the gem 'protected_attributes' awhile back when trying to figure this out.  Is this what is forcing me to use the attr_accessible statement in the user.rb?

If there is any additional code that would be useful just ask.  Thanks for taking a look, it's much appreciated as I start to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should have just attempted this myself before asking here.  I removed the gem 'protected_attributes' and commented out the attr_accessible line and restarted rails and viola, it still works. :D